# Windbg with SOS, stopping on the correct exception

Tags: .net, debugging, windows-services, windbg, sos

I have a windows service that is, intermittently, throwing an exception that sometimes kills its SQLConnection, and other times kills the service completely. It is running live on a customer's site.

I have planned to use Windbg + SOS on it to get a crash dump, so that I can debug this at my own leisure.

On my first attempt, however, the debugger halted the service when it hit a first chance exception that was being caught and handled in the code (as I used the `sxe clr` command).

The help file appears to suggest I use `sxd clr`, instead of `sxe clr`, to capture second change exceptions instead of first chance exceptions.

In my testing, however, a generated, caught and handled exception is being treated exactly the same as a thrown exception (but not caught) by the `sxd clr` command, namely it's noted and ignored.

Is this behaviour, of not stopping on a thrown exception, possibly as I threw the exception explicitly in my code, or are will all clr exceptions fail to halt the debugger with the `sxd` command? Should I be using a different command?

Secondly, As Windbg doesn't specifically recognise clr errors, is it possible to tell it to stop only on a specific, unhandled, exception (i.e. InvalidOperationException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier just to use adplus for creating the dump file. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163530.aspx) shows how to create minidumps for specific .NET exceptions using adplus.

If you're working with WinDbg, you need the [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) extension and a command like

```
sxe -c "!soe System.InvalidOperationException 1; .if (@$t1==1){!pe} .else{g}" clr
```

Comment: Keep in mind that adplus.vbs was replaced with adplus.exe in the latest version of WinDbg. I have had a few issues with the new version, so you may need to use the old version, which is still included (renamed to adplus_old.vbs).